# add another options in action button in tree view odoo 10

Tags: python-2.7, button, treeview, odoo-10

I want to add another options in action button on tree view. Moreover in export and delete, i want to add "Confirm" options. I don't know how, please help me. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <record id="action_id" model="ir.actions.server">
                <field name="name">name</field>
                <field name="model_id" ref="module_name.model_object_name" />
                <field name="code">
                    action = model.function_name()
                </field>
            </record>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do by this way:

```
<record id="id" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Confirm Order</field>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
        <field name="res_model">custom.model.name</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">form</field>
        <field name="target">new</field>
    </record>
```

If you want to add custom group for this option then you can add one attribute here also like:

```
<field name="groups_id" eval="[(4,ref('model.group_name'))]"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make a popup wizard appear in a different model with this:

```
<act_window id="module_name.your_custom_action_name"
                name="your_custom_name"
                src_model="model.in.wich.you.want.to.add.the.action"
                res_model="model.in.wich.the.action.resides"
                view_mode="form"
                target="new"
                multi="True"/>
```